# Is it possible in typescript to enforce a number with 0 decimal digits?

Tags: typescript

```
type InputValue: number;

function(value: InputValue) {
   // do something here
}
```

There is not `int` number in Typescript (only `BigInt`)

**How to enforce value has 0 decimal digit (i.e. it's not a float number) as a type without additional logic / type assertions?**

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible in TypeScript specification. You can find better answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897742/how-do-you-specify-that-a-class-property-is-an-integer)

Comment: You cannot enforce that via the type system, only via code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you specify that a class property is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897742/how-do-you-specify-that-a-class-property-is-an-integer)

Comment: I guess the answer is no then. how can I close the question on my own?

Comment: @dragonmnl, You should watch https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39784 for this feature (since this may add `i32/64` support to TypeScript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to enforce value has 0 decimal digit (i.e. it's not a float number) as a type without additional logic / type assertions?

TypeScript does not support an `int` data type.

## Why

Because JavaScript doesn't support it. [TypeScript is just JavaScript with type annotations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cj8z91XuOv8).