# How to enforce datatype of key and value in map in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I'm creating a `map` like this:

```
let myMap = new Map();
```

We know that `key` and `value` both can be of any type.
But I've a requirement where I need to enforce Integer for the key and String for the value.

For e.g.:

```
1 => 'Apple'
2 => 'Ball'
3 => 'Cat'
```

Any attempt to violate this rule should be checked at compile time itself.
But I'm getting syntax errors when I try to do somewhat similar:

```
  let myMap = new Map<integer,string>();
```

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you specify that a class property is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897742/how-do-you-specify-that-a-class-property-is-an-integer)

Comment: @Ivar, no not really. I'm still looking for answers

Comment: This is confusing. You have tagged this question with TypeScript and are talking about "compile time", but you are _not_ using TypeScript? JavaScript itself doesn't have compile time type checking, so that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes, i agree. I think i made it complex. Let's stick to the point that I want to enforce data type in map in JS

Comment: Like I said, JavaScript itself doesn't support type checking at compile time. Best you can do is to wrap around the `.add()` and check if the types are correct before inserting the values. Either that, or switch to TypeScript, which does support compile time type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript, you can use:

```
 const myMap: Map<number, string> = new Map<number, string>();
```

Unfortunately you can't do this kind of check in Javascript.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`

Comment: just to be sure, are you using TypeScript or JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript as mentioned in question

Comment: You should remove the typescript tag then. You can't use typing in Javascript, that's a Typescript feature. There is no way to do this kind of compile check in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript dosn't have an `integer` type only `number`. Therefor you would need to define it like so.

```
 let myMap = new Map<number,string>();
```

You can define a setter in which you validate the key like so

```
Number.isInteger(data) // returns weither or not data is an int
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in itself doesn't provide any syntax to support generic classes

You can try writing using this class below, which extends Map.

```
class Map2 extends Map{

    constructor(keyType, valueType){
        super()
        this._keyType = keyType;
        this._valueType = valueType;
        
    }


    _matchesType(key,value){
        return (typeof(key) === this._keyType) && (typeof(value) === this._valueType);
    }


    set(key, value){
       if(!this._matchesType(key,value))
             throw 'Type Mismatch Exception';
       super.set(key,value)
    }

}
```

Then use Map2 instead of normal Map, with types in the constructor.
Like this,

```
const m2 = new Map2('number', 'string');

m2.set(1,'apple');
m2.get(1); //returns 'apple'

m2.set('test', 'test value') // throws Type Mismatch Exception
```