# javascript/typescript: enforce integer input (with performance in mind)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Since I'm not a native js/ts programmer this caught me a bit of guard. I'm writing a math function which can only take integers or it crashes. Therefore I must enforce this rule somehow.

(ps If this is a dublicate I am sorry, but I couldn't find the answer.)

My fist attempt was:

```
function math(a) {
    if(a % 1 != 0) return NaN;
    // to mathy stuff
    return b;
}
```

But since this function will get called **A LOT** I wanted, if possible, something with a smaller impact on performance. After googling a bit I found this native function:

```
function math(a) {
    if(!Number.isInteger(a)) return NaN;
    // to mathy stuff
    return b;
}
```

Although performance wise it's not much of a difference. The next option would be to take a BigInt as input (which I can enforce with typescript at least).

```
let num: number = 0;
let c: BigInt = math(BigInt(num));

function math(a: bigint) {
    // to mathy stuff
    return b;
}
```

But than I would have to explicitly convert the number to a BitInt. And there are probably many reasons why this isn't a good idea...

So whats the most performance efficient way to enforce an interger input. (I'm fine with compile time (ts) solutions, but something in runtime would be even better (js)).

Comment: I doubt that verifying the parameter is an integer would be a significant part of the function, assuming it does something useful. I would use `if (a === +a && Number.isInteger(a))` probably, but there are other ways. Really significant performance gains usually are made through algorithmic improvement and not little things like this.

Comment: I'd say you should not worry about typing inside your module -- only on its public surface. If the function is a public API, consider adding typical use cases that take input, check it once, then do some heavy lifting by calling your function many times, i.e. some kind of batch processing. Also, what will happen if you pass non-integer there? If the code crashes, then so be it, you can wrap it with try/catch and rethrow your own tailored error message. If it does not crash, them maybe passing non-integer is not a problem at all? Another way is to force integer with `x | 0`, or `~~x`, etc.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65436661/3431180) that uses AssemblyScript (a variant of TS) from a similar question. AS has an `int32` type and could be performant in WASM.

For runtime types, see the [`typescript-runtime-type-benchmarks` repo](https://github.com/moltar/typescript-runtime-type-benchmarks). It compares many runtime typing libraries by performance.
[`spectypes`](https://github.com/iyegoroff/spectypes) and [`ts-runtime-checks`](https://github.com/GoogleFeud/ts-runtime-checks) are currently at the top, but require a compile-time dependency.